# Iterating an array in Ruby and adding a string after a number

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I iterate through an array of numbers, and add a string to the output in each iteration? I'm using "puts" to display the number.

The array

```
nums = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Iterating the array

```
for i in nums
    puts i + " Carrots"
end
```

I'm getting this response

```
test.rb:40:in `+': String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

Comment: Convert the integer into string: `i.to_s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Using `to_s`

You can use `to_s` to convert integer to string.

```
nums = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in nums
    puts i.to_s + " Carrots"
end
```

output:

```
1 Carrots
2 Carrots
3 Carrots
4 Carrots
5 Carrots
```

### Method 2: Using String Interpolations

```
nums = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in nums
    puts "#{i}  Carrots"
end
```

Output:

```
1  Carrots
2  Carrots
3  Carrots
4  Carrots
5  Carrots
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].product([" Carrots"]).map(&:join)
#⇒ 1 Carrots
#  2 Carrots
#  3 Carrots
#  4 Carrots
#  5 Carrots
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number using the method to_s and concatenate with +, or use interpolation, but looping with **for** doesn't feels like the ruby way

**Using iterators**

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

nums.each do |num|
  puts num.to_s + ' Carrots'
end

nums.each do |num|
  puts "#{num} Carrots"
end
```

**Note:** Use simple quotes if interpolation is not going to be used

**More elegant one line solution**

```
puts nums.map {|num| num.to_s + ' Carrots'}

puts nums.map {|num| "#{num} Carrots"}
```